# How do I send post data to my server side node.js application?

Tags: node.js, forms, express, post, frontend

I have a server side node js application which sends me all of the facebook posts from a specified page since a desired date.

Up until now I have been running the application on my terminal using `npm start [facebook page name] [sinceDate]`.

Now that my app is running smoothly I would like to add some front end into the mix. On an index.html page (located at `app/views/index.html`) I have created an input form which takes in the `facebook page name` and `sincedate` arguments.

I was wondering if anyone had any advice on how to send this `post` data to my server side node application?

Here's a list of my dependencies, let me know if there's anything I need to elaborate on:

```
"dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.7.10",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "request": "^2.79.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.1.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send post notification using Ajax call.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/your/controller",
        data: myData,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
    }).success(function (result) {
        // Do something with responce
    });
```

So, next step is to make route on node.js server side for incoming requests. For example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use('/your/controller', {

    router.post('/', function (req, res, next){
        var requestedData = req.body.myData;

        res.status(200).end();    
    });
});
```

Hope this help.